# Memory stream length always zero

Tags: c#, memorystream

when running the following code, my memory stream always has a length of zero (documentStream.length)

I've tried setting resetting the position to zero which seems to solve for most, but im still getting a zero length?

```
public MemoryStream CreateDocumentTest()
    {
        MemoryStream documentStream = new MemoryStream();

        WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
            WordprocessingDocument.Create(documentStream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

        mainPart.Document = new Document();
        Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
        Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
        Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
        run.AppendChild(new Text("Create text in body - CreateWordprocessingDocument"));

        wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
        wordDocument.Save();
        documentStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return documentStream;
    }
```

Comment: Please post code as text. Images should be reserved for GUI errors and such that cannot be represented by text. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to share the code in the question itself and not in the image

Comment: Based on title https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+Memory+stream+length+always+zero+site%3astackoverflow.com this is duplicate.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i had already searched and found that answer, but it didnt solve my problem (the issue isnt releated to the stream pos... i mentioned that in my question) however, i have managed to get it working and will post an answer now

Comment: ok... i cant post an answer because this question has been removed.... answer was I changed to use a public property for the memory stream, and changed my funtion to a void, then wrapped the "WordprocessingDocument wordDocument" in a "using", now it works

Comment: have finally got around to adding my answer... if you downvoted my question because of the image, i have changed that now to script as requested... feel free to change your vote :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How i fixed this, I adjusted the CreateDocumentTest method to be void, and i had a public property for MemoryStream

I also, wrapped the building in a "Using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument...)", and ended the method with setting my public property

Now, im not sure if it was using the public property, or applying the "using", or both, but it now works... here is the updated code

```
        public void CreateDocumentTest()
        {

            DocumentStream = new MemoryStream();

            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
                WordprocessingDocument.Create(DocumentStream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

                mainPart.Document = new Document();
                Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
                Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
                Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
                run.AppendChild(new Text("Create text in body - CreateWordprocessingDocument"));

                wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();

                DocumentStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            }
        }
```